# FieldNotFoundException Error in MarketDataIncrementalRefresh message QuickFix

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix

I am working on sample application which has FixAcceptor and FixInitiator. I am sending MarketDataRequest message from initiator and send MarketDataIncrementalRefresh message from Acceptor but getting error of FieldNotFound exception for NoMDEntries message. I am pretty sure I am send wrong message from acceptor but not able to find. please help if any body can.

This is Fix initiator message

Send MarketDataRequest

string symbol = "MSFT";
            //Sending MarketData Requests
            QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest marketDataRequest = new QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest();

```
        marketDataRequest.set(new MDReqID("1"));
        marketDataRequest.set(new SubscriptionRequestType('1'));
        marketDataRequest.set(new MarketDepth(1));
        marketDataRequest.set(new MDUpdateType(1));
        marketDataRequest.set(new AggregatedBook(true));
        marketDataRequest.set(new NoMDEntryTypes(2));
        QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypes group = new QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypes();
        group.set(new MDEntryType('0'));
        marketDataRequest.addGroup(group);
        group.set(new MDEntryType('1'));
        marketDataRequest.addGroup(group);
        marketDataRequest.set(new NoRelatedSym(1));
        QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym group2 = new QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym();
        group2.set(new Symbol(symbol));
        marketDataRequest.addGroup(group2);

        //Send message
        Session.sendToTarget(marketDataRequest, sessionID);
```

FixAcceptor Code

public override void onMessage(QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest message, SessionID session)
        {
            var relatedSymbol = new QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym();

```
        Group g = message.getGroup(1, relatedSymbol);

        string symbol=relatedSymbol.get(new Symbol()).getValue();

        Console.WriteLine("Got marketdata request for Symbol {0}", symbol );

       // Thread.Sleep(1000);

        QuickFix42.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh prices = new QuickFix42.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh();

        prices.set(new MDReqID("1"));


        var mp = new QuickFix42.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries();

        mp.set(new MDUpdateAction('0'));//tag 279
        //price type
        mp.set(new MDEntryType('0'));//tag:269

        mp.set(new MDEntrySize(2345));
        //Symbol
        mp.set(new Symbol(symbol));
        //Price of the Market Data Entry.
        mp.set(new MDEntryPx(36.45d));

        prices.addGroup(mp);



        try
        {
            Session.sendToTarget(prices, session);
        }
        catch (SessionNotFound) { }


    }
```

Receiving MarketDataIncrementalRefresh message in FixAcceptor

```
 public override void onMessage(MarketDataIncrementalRefresh message, SessionID session)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("MarketDataIncrementalRefresh : " + message.ToString());

            MDReqID mdreqid = new MDReqID();
            NoMDEntries nomdentries = new NoMDEntries();
            QuickFix42.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries group
                = new QuickFix42.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries();
            MDUpdateAction mdupdateaction = new MDUpdateAction();
            DeleteReason deletereason = new DeleteReason();
            MDEntryType mdentrytype = new MDEntryType();
            MDEntryID mdentryid = new MDEntryID();
            Symbol symbol = new Symbol();
            MDEntryOriginator mdentryoriginator = new MDEntryOriginator();
            MDEntryPx mdentrypx = new MDEntryPx();
            Currency currency = new Currency();
            MDEntrySize mdentrysize = new MDEntrySize();
            ExpireDate expiredate = new ExpireDate();
            ExpireTime expiretime = new ExpireTime();
            NumberOfOrders numberoforders = new NumberOfOrders();
            MDEntryPositionNo mdentrypositionno = new MDEntryPositionNo();
            Text text = new Text();

            //message.get(mdreqid);
            message.get(nomdentries);
            int list = nomdentries.getValue();
            if (message.isSetNoMDEntries())
                for (uint i = 0; i < list; i++)
                {

                    message.getGroup(i + 1, group);
                    //group.get(mdupdateaction);
                    //if (mdupdateaction.getValue() == '2')
                    //    Console.WriteLine("Enter");
                    ////group.get(deletereason);
                    //group.get(mdentrytype);
                    group.get(mdentryid);
                    group.get(symbol);
                    //group.get(mdentryoriginator);
                    if (mdupdateaction.getValue() == '0')
                        group.get(mdentrypx);
                    //group.get(currency);
                    //if (mdupdateaction.getValue() == '0')
                    //  group.get(mdentrysize);
                    //group.get(expiredate);
                    //group.get(expiretime);
                    //if (mdupdateaction.getValue() == '0')
                    //  group.get(numberoforders);
                    //group.get(mdentrypositionno);
                    //group.get(text);

                    //if (mdupdateaction.getValue() == '0')
                    //{
                    //    for (int x = 0; x < mainapp.MDlist.Length; x++)
                    //    {
                    //        if (symbol.ToString() == mainapp.MDlist[x].Symbol)
                    //        {
                    //            if (mdentrytype.getValue() == '0')
                    //                mainapp.MDlist[x].Bid = (float)mdentrypx.getValue();
                    //            else if (mdentrytype.getValue() == '1')
                    //                mainapp.MDlist[x].Ask = (float)mdentrypx.getValue();
                    //        }
                    //    }
                    //}
                }




            Console.WriteLine("Got Symbol {0} Price {1}", symbol.getValue(), mdentrypx.getValue());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

but getting error FieldNotFoundException at

message.getGroup(i + 1, group);

Comment: without the correct tags there's a little chance to get an answer

Comment: I am getting this as MarketDataIncrementalRefresh MEssage {8=FIX.4.29=11135=X34=10749=FixServer52=20120217-13:20:57.81456=CLIENT155=MSFT262=MSFT01268=1269=0270=36.45271=234510=008}

Comment: by tags I meant the tags that you attach to the question... which language is it, c#?

Answer (score 0):

```
int list = nomdentries.getValue();
```

Your problem is this line. Only use getGroup if list isn't 0. You have this value and you don't need this

```
if (message.isSetNoMDEntries())
```

And why aren't you doing this

```
for (uint i = 1; i <= list; ++i)
{
    message.getGroup(i, group);
```

And could you paste across a FIX message you receive, broken down properly, rather than a hazy string. You would be in a better position if you try breaking down your FIX string.

Your message is incomplete as it is missing a mandatory tag 279. Check this [website](http://fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/) for what are the required and not required fields in a message. Would help you in finding your error more easily.

Comment: message is 8=FIX.4.2|9=142|35=X|34=107|43=Y|49=FixServer|52=20120217-17:25:02.286|56=CLIENT1|122=20120217-13:20:57.814|55=MSFT|262=MSFT01|268=1|269=0|270=36.45|271=2345|10=012|

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it and issue was path for data dictionary was wrong and was not point to right data dictionary file.